# Middleman dynamic page / url rewrite with wildcard

Tags: url-rewriting, middleman, dynamic-pages

I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite URLs to create dynamic pages with Middleman (3.0.12). Here's my attempt:

```
activate :directory_indexes
# not found
page "list/*", :proxy => "index.html"
# loads index
page "list/index.html", :proxy => "index.html"
```

Basically I need to create a simple rewrite rule to forward all list/* traffic to the index page which is then handled by AngularJS's HTML5 router. I know this will work on the live site with htaccess, but developing without it is annoying. Is this possible in Middle Man?

Thanks in advance,

Casey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got a solution straight from Thomas Reynolds, author of Middleman:

In Gemfile

```
gem 'rack-rewrite', '~> 1.2.1'
```

In config.rb

```
require 'rack/rewrite'
use Rack::Rewrite do
  rewrite %r{^\/list(.*)}, '/index.html'
end
```